# Why does nothing change when I attempt to restore a backup?

Tags: 7, drush, backups

I have a drupal 7.43 installation and it has been doing regular backups using the Backup and Restore module.  I wanted to do a restore but I'm blocked at every turn it seems.  I go to Configuration >> System >> Backup and Migrate >> Saved Backups and click on "restore" next to the one I want to restore from.  I get a new page where I choose "Entire Site" to restore to, as that is what I'm backing up, and then click "Restore." That takes me to a white page.  When I reload my site, nothing has changed, so I assume this means failure, although I have no way of knowing what failed or why that I can tell.

So I tried drush:

```
drush bam-restore archive scheduled drupal.xxxxx.net-2016-03-21T09-44-17.sitearchive.tar.gz
```

This gave me a mysterious error:

> Restoring will delete some or all of your data and cannot be undone. ALWAYS TEST YOUR BACKUPS ON A NON-PRODUCTION SERVER!
>   Are you sure you want to perform the restore? (y/n): y
>   PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function file_directory_path() in /var/www/drupal.wealthychef.net/public_html/sites/all/modules/backup_migrate/includes/sources.archivesource.inc on line 211
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   Error: Call to undefined function file_directory_path() in
>       /var/www/drupal.wealthychef.net/public_html/sites/all/modules/backup_migrate/includes/sources.archivesource.inc,
>       line 211

Can someone help me understand how to restore my site?

Comment: I'm pretty sure backup migrate doesn't delete new data like fields etc. so you need to do it on a clean database. Try it on dev server with a new installation, only your sites folder copied and backup migrate enabled.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a bug of Backup and Migrate module, since [`file_directory_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_directory_path/6) no longer exists in Drupal 7.

So instead of `file_directory_path()` you should use:

```
file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_scheme(file_default_scheme())->getDirectoryPath()
```

or:

```
variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files')
```

So please upgrade your module to development version (but it's not fixed yet at time of writing) or use this patch available at: [#2618516 - Fatal error when restoring "Entire Site"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2618516) which goes like:

```
--- a/includes/sources.archivesource.inc
+++ b/includes/sources.archivesource.inc
@@ -208,7 +208,7 @@ class backup_migrate_files_destination_archivesource extends backup_migrate_dest

       // Move the files from the temp directory.
       if ($filepath && file_exists($filepath)) {
-        _backup_migrate_move_files($filepath, file_directory_path());
+        _backup_migrate_move_files($filepath, variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files') );
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of the Backup Migrate module you may have this bug https://www.drupal.org/node/2618516 - try upgrading the Backup Migrate module and see if you can then restore.

Don't forget to search Google/Duckduckgo/your-favourite-search-engine for issues, and if it is related to a specific module there is no harm in looking in the issue queue for similar issues...